# ValueError: Points must be Nx2 array, got 2x5

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an animation and am looking at the code of another stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610210/how-to-animate-scatter-plot-over-time-using-python). The code is the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as animation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

u = u"""Time    M1  M2  M3  M4  M5
1       1   2   3   1   2
2       1   3   3   1   2
3       1   3   2   1   3
4       2   2   3   1   2
5       3   3   3   1   3
6       2   3   4   1   4
7       2   3   4   3   3
8       3   4   4   3   4
9       4   4   5   3   3
10      4   4   5   5   4"""

df_Bubble = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

time_count = len(df_Bubble) 
colors = np.arange(1, 6) 
x = np.arange(1, 6) 
max_radius = 25 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
pic = ax.scatter(x, df_Bubble.iloc[0, 1:], s=100, c=colors) 
pic.set_offsets([[np.nan]*len(colors)]*2)
ax.axis([0,7,0,7])

def init(): 
    pic.set_offsets([[np.nan]*len(colors)]*2)
    return pic,

def updateData(i): 
    y = df_Bubble.iloc[i, 1:] 
    area = np.pi * (max_radius * y / 10.0) ** 2 
    pic.set_offsets([x, y.values]) 
    pic._sizes = area
    i+=1 
    return pic, 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateData, 
      frames=10, interval = 50, blit=True, init_func=init) 

plt.show()
```

When I run this code unchanged I get the error

```
ValueError: Points must be Nx2 array, got 2x5
```

I have looked at similar threads on this question and have come to the conclusion that the problem has to do with the line with [[np.nan]*len(colors)]*2. Based on the examples I found, I thought that changing a part of this line to an array might help, but none of my attempts have worked, and now I'm stuck. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_offsets` expects a `Nx2` ndarray and you provide 2 arrays with 5 elements each in `updateData(i)` and 2 lists with 5 elements each in `init()`

```py
def init(): 
    pic.set_offsets(np.empty((len(colors),2)))
    return pic,

def updateData(i):
    y = df_Bubble.iloc[i, 1:] 
    area = np.pi * (max_radius * y / 10.0) ** 2
    #pic.set_offsets(np.hstack([x[:i,np.newaxis], y.values[:i, np.newaxis]]))
    pic.set_offsets(np.transpose((x, y.values)))
    pic._sizes = area
    i+=1 
    return pic,
```